# Should I tell my co-workers that branch manager uses drugs (crack) at the office?

Tags: management

I worked in New York City at a mid-sized brokerage house. The place was open round the clock so if you needed, you can practically live there - included shower, changing rooms etc. The managing director was a great guy who has the one office with the boardroom taking up the remaining available space. So after about 2 years working there, I come in on a Friday or Saturday night after bar hopping alone at maybe 2-3am, and I don't see anyone else.

So while walking around, I look on the branch manager's desk and see a lighter shaped like a butane mini canister, size of a D battery next to glass pipes and vials. I recognized that it was crack, and I got out of there fast.

This is the guy who makes important decisions. I have no proof, as I didn't have a camera phone, so no evidence.

What would be the course of action to take where I don't end up unemployed and industry blacklisted?

Comment: ****comments removed****:  Please avoid using comments for extended discussion. Instead, please use [chat]. On Workplace SE, comments are intended to help improve a post. Please see [What "comments" are not...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) for more details.

Comment: @jmort253 I can understand removing *some* comments, but all of them seems a bit excessive?

Comment: @Joe - It may seem that way, and I try to take the time to look at each comment and make a call individually, but if the entire comment thread is nothing but debate or extended discussion, then it simply doesn't belong in the main Q&A site. Comments are intended to either help improve a post or seek clarification from its author. I realize the contents of this posts is a popular, debatable topic, so [join our very active discussion-based chat room and start a conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler). Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253 (at risk of making this chatty)... the reason I say this, is I added a comment which wasn't chatty, and intended as advice, but not enough detail to qualify as an answer, this was removed with the rest of the comments, I don't mind too much, but it seems like this, plus any other potentially helpful comments got caught up in it.

Comment: Hey @joe, even answers in comments is something we discourage because they can't be ranked, voted on, nor do they appear in search results. See [What do we do about comments as answers](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1832/98), as well as [What comments are not](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/72/98) for further guidance. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: I want my comment back. I was proud of it and it had 3 up-votes.

Comment: I don't think this question should be changed since it offers a number of diverse answers for anyone in a similar situation to look and evaluate. I can write what I did, and what happen if anyone cares and its permitted. Otherwise Mike's answer is what I should have done probably, and Haylem's answer is closest to what I did do.

Comment: Step 1. Remove all description from question needed to answer it, gutting it in essence.

Step 2. Delete dozens of comments from confused readers who can't understand the situation due to Step 1.

Step 3. Close the question and ask OP to rewrite it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would say that without any proof, you are on pretty shaky ground and it would come down to his word versus yours and it's likely that the more senior employee would be believed either by the MD or your co-workers.

Personally (and this is without experience of working for this type of firm/in the broker industry), if it is not noticeably affecting his ability to do his job, then it is of no business of anyones. Unless there are strict clauses in employment contracts about behaviour whilst on the company premises that he is contravening then he is not really doing anything wrong.

I'm not sure what would be gained by mentioning this to your co-workers unless you already have an issue with the branch manager for some other reason.

Comment: While I agree that the OP has no evidence and should not bring it up, I have to disagree that this is no business of the company. He is doing something illegal on company property, that is certainly their business whether the work is being affected or not.

Comment: @HLGEM - by "company", do you mean his superiors or the OP's co-workers as referenced in the title of the question?

Comment: @Mike - his employers. The people who are hiring him. The legal entity that is the company.

Comment: @Oded - thanks, I understand that. But that is not the question the OP is asking. He is asking if he should tell his co-workers.

Comment: @Mike - Sure. Which is the completely wrong question...

Comment: Your opinion of if his use of the drugs is anyone elses business is not approiate in an answer at SE

Comment: "*I'm not sure what would be gained*" - perhaps nothing, but if the manager does indeed abuse drugs, the employees should know this from an ethical standpoint. The question is whether the potential fallout (started nasty rumors about old boss!) outweighs the ethical consideration.

Comment: @Superbest: Why assume that it's at the level of _abuse_? Or even _more than once_?

Comment: There are also security implications for the company, if he is in a position of trust the fact the manager uses drugs could be used to blackmail the manager. This alone has the *potential* to impact the company. I'd point out, I'm not suggesting the OP blackmail the manager, but explaining why even if its not hurting anyone *yet*, it might cause a negative impact on the company later.

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir It's illegal. Wouldn't any use at all automatically be abuse?

Comment: @Superbest: I rather assumed that by "abuse" they meant it in the same way you say "alcohol abuse", in that the substance is being used _too much_ so that it impairs function and reduces quality of life, and so on. I've never seen it used any other way.
But, either way, it still stands that this may have been a one time or very rare use, that does not impair his ability to work, and he has no evidence (at least shared with us) otherwise.

Comment: If someone is actually taking the risk of using at work, it is extremely unlikely that their dependency has not risen to the level of being a problem.  Either that or they're arrogant idiots, which is also a problem for the company. However, see the footnote on my answer.

Comment: Given the track record of NY financial institutions, I don't think the legalities of what goes on in the office is of any consequences.

Answer (score 20):

Co-workers? Absolutely not. Not your job, not your role, no good results likely.

Upper management? Maybe cautiously. You may want to advise them of what you saw -- and only what you saw, without any speculation about what or who -- and leave it to them to take whatever action they consider appropriate. Check whether your company has a mechanism for raising concerns anonymously. Remember that you're betting your job even if you do file anonymously, as management may decide to shut down the entire site or otherwise take less than targeted action.

Whatever you do, *don't* tamper with evidence. Not your job unless you're in Security and appropriately trained, in which case you wouldn't be asking the Internet. Untrained, you're likely to make matters worse rather than better (and may just get yourself in trouble). If you feel a need to capture something, you could consider grabbing a cell-phone photo... but think about whether you want that image on your phone.

Comment: As you point out just tell upper mangement what they saw, don't conclude anything, people are smart they can come to their own conclusion.

Comment: One other thought: If you just saw the paraphernalia sitting on the desk, it could be there because the manager had just confiscated it from someone else and was waiting for someone from Legal to come by and tell him how to safely dispose of it and/or transfer it to police. Another good reason to limit yourself to observed facts rather than jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 9):

Too many possibilities. Someone, anyone, such as a janitor, the guy who has the desk next to yours, a secretary, any other co-worker, etc., etc., was using that desk to do drugs. But perhaps  ***not*** the branch manager who is actually assigned that desk/office. The drug user goes for a nature call, then you walk in.

No evidence whatsoever who is the user or who the stuff belongs to on the desk. Perhaps someone trying to frame the branch manager. *The list of scenarios is endless.*

Your only option was to pick up the stuff, like in the cop shows with a tissue, bag it and take it to senior management. Tell them where you found it and mention that you doubt it's the branch manager, but someone is obviously doing something. Even better is you drop that evidence off anonymously with a note; no one likes a snitch (even a worthy one), not even subconsciously. Then it's up to management and, if they like, they can have it fingerprinted by a private detective agency.

One word of note, drugs in the workplace is more about liability coverage and insurance payout as well as protecting the brokerage from customer lawsuits.

Comment: Do not drop the evidence off anonymously, as that will leave management to wonder if YOU are planting evidence.

Comment: I like the general tone but you shouldn't touch the evidence, for no reason whatsoever. If you find something suspicious, get a phone and call security. Let them handle it. If someone tries to tamper with the evidence, you should try to stop them (with words, not by hitting them over the head).

Comment: zacharydl- If the fingerprints on the crack vial belong to whomever, then how is that planting evidence? Digulla - Where is security at the late hour this occurred and do you want to wait around for them? Are they true security agents or just rent-a-cops/night watchman. If you don't grab the evidence it could be removed by someone and the real user will never be discovered.

Comment: This is insane. You could be caught with that "evidence" while you are carrying it, and being accused yourself!

Answer (score 7):

I thought I'd just add another answer because I don't see any that offers what seems the best option to me... and that honestly baffles me.

### TALK TO THE GUY!!

**Pros:**

- He **might** be more careful.
- He **might** realize it's time to use less.
- He **might** appreciate your concern for him AND the company.

**Cons:**

- He **might** not like you because of it. Big deal. Apparently you don't like him for it.
- He **might** not like you because you falsely accused. At least you didn't report him for nothing then.

Nothing more to fear from that. He can't get you fired or closeted just for knowing something he doesn't want anyone else to know. The absolutely worst case and unlikely scenario would be if he's doing it, his supervisors are doing it, and there's no omerta about it and they decide you're a snotty annoyance they need to get rid off. Sounds Hollywoddian.

---

This might sound like I live in the magic land of licorns and hugbears, but that seems like the best first step to me, albeit maybe a possibly uncomfortable one.

Then, depending on the outcome, you can consider other options.

Comment: (and seriously, when I read answers or comment about directly reporting the guy to law enforcement for _using_ and not _selling_, I'm thinking we lack some humanity around here... Considering a code of conduct and company policy, fine, but going to law enforcement as the step 0 seems sadly aggressive to me.)

Comment: +1, but I'd do that only if you think that (aside from the crack use) the manager is actually a decent person. If you suspect he might be a vindicative/untrusting person, steer clear of trouble

Comment: @berdario: yeah there's obviously no reason to reach out to a violent nut who would go American Psycho on you. But it'd still generally be my first step before a mediation by a supervisor.

Comment: @haylem So at end of meeting i say ... These bastards bugged your office, you were lucky this time. I got all the tapes, say no more. My lips are sealed. Say Frankie, you don't mind me calling you that right? I got your back, tough guy but so you're in luck, you know why Frankie? Because I like you, I really do. But see, I'm not feeling the love back from u. O! That Facebook IPO transition team announcement is today! Of course! You were gonna surprise me, and here I am being a jerk thinking you don't appreciate me, and you were gonna surprise me with putting me as the lead and a new office.

Comment: @NastyNick: that'd be one way to do it, though I didn't really think of "blackmail" as part of the the human element in my approach. :) But for better effect, you should wait for him in his office, in his chair with your back turned to the door, so you can slowly turn back towards him as he enters. Big grin or cold stare, your pick. And with a cat. White works better, but I guess any cat would do. Props like guns and baseball bats are also a nice touch, but they're harder to get through security than the cat.

Comment: Excuse me - you're talking about a (potential) crack user who needs to cover his ass. Quick - what's gonna happen? (Cue mood lighting and choir singing "Kum By Yah") He's going to see you trying to make a positive impact on his life? Ummm...NO! He's going to see you as a huge threat to his existence! There's NO WAY to "talk to this guy". You shut up (as in, don't tell momma, don't tell girlfriend, don't tell your priest!), you get another job, and you bail. End. Of. Story.

Comment: @BobJarvis: That's a safe approach for your ass and I can understand it. But there's a disconnect between the first part of your answer with the word "potential" and the rest which is totally assertive about things being necessarily the worst possible case. Plus, you know, not everybody can necessarily afford to quit their job every time they've got a moron for a boss.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few options;

Get proof, then report him, if it breaks any company policy.  In most typical companies this probably would break some form of Code of Conduct (if your company has one).

Think of it as if you are in court, the two lawyers could talk a great game to the jury, but it's the evidence that create a guilty verdict or reasonable doubt.

Get your ducks in order (evidence) first.

Some may think of you whistleblower and that would be the case yes. However if your company does have a CoC handbook, refer to it as most comprehensives CoC's have a whistleblowing section - how to do it properly.

Another suggestion could be talking to a HR representative for anonymous advice.

As long as you follow things by the book you 'should' be OK.

However since you said you have no evidence, then you cannot do anything about that instance. Don't turn into a Columbo and attempt to catch him in the act, concentrate on your own role, but be aware.

Thanks @Chad for your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

I once reported to a guy who always had a suspiciously high level of energy. And that's how I described it when asked about him.

You don't know what you think you saw, you didn't record it, and you honestly don't know (although you think you do, and I did read your original expanded question). Bottom line, if you want a reputation as someone with good judgement, discretion, and loyalty, you don't say a word unless you have proof and ethics demands it. In this case, if you had proof, ethics would demand it based on most corporate policies. But you don't. So hold your tongue.

Comment: Downvote? Feedback would be nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you have no proof.  Even if you had taken a photo, this still wouldn't be proof.  Anyone can plant evidence on someone's desk and take a photo.  It proves nothing.
2. How can you even be 100% sure of what it was?  Did you pick it up and inspect it?  It sounds like you just got spooked and left quickly.  Are you really willing to destroy someone's career because you have a 'good hunch' that they're doing drugs?  And even if it was what you think it was, that's still not proof of any wrongdoing.  Sometimes people come into possession of things, who knows how or why.  There may be a perfectly good explanation.
3. It's the 21st century, lighten up.  Do you have any idea how common drug-use is in brokerage houses?  If the guy is doing his job well, who cares?  If he's not performing his job well, then report him, but on the grounds of job performance which is really the only thing that matters.

Comment: ****comments removed****:  Please avoid using comments for extended discussion. Instead, please use [chat]. On Workplace SE, comments are intended to help improve a post. Please see [What "comments" are not...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) for more details.

Comment: Hey T, just some constructive feedback: I'd suggest removing the opinionated portions (ex: "lighten up") and try to come at this from a more *objective* approach. Workplace SE is subjective, but we're looking for answers that can ideally be backed with facts, references, or personal experiences. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for details. In essence, objectivity avoids the extended debate we were seeing in this comment thread. Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent and realistic advice.

Answer (score -1):

Don't accuse him directly.

Instead, encourage your workplace to enforce random drug testing. Let him get caught naturally, or give them up naturally. Either way you don't get caught up in the mess.

And, you could be wrong about him using drugs, despite how sure you are. Maybe he was going to do a presentation at a youth group on the dangers of drugs.

Comment: this looks like a nice idea, except that it lacks details on how could a regular employee "enforce random drug testing"? I for one have no slightest idea on how this could be achieved

Comment: ... why? This doesn't explain "why" at all nor does it really suggest why it is right.

Comment: @gnat where I come from "get" can be used as a synonym of "compel" or "urge". I have edited it to. "encourage"

Answer (score -2):

Mention **only** to the security people at the firm what you saw - and **only** what you saw, not your interpretation.

Then go about your business and forget it, until if and when it impacts you directly. You are not the police, the security team, the HR team, or the provider of company gossip.